# sendmailR with sendmail server?

Tags: r, sendmailr

I'm running rstudio server in a docker container, hadleyverse, running on top of Ubuntu
I would like to be able to send an email from there. I tried following [this](http://www.danielreed.org/blog/sendmailr.html) tutorial and wrote this code:

```
#Load library
library(sendmailR)

#Set mail options (i.e., port number)
sendmail_options(smtpPort=25)

#Send notification and results
sendmail(from="R notification", 
         to="MY@EMAIL.COM", 
         msg="test", 
         subject="R script has finished")
```

But I get the following error

```
Error in socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) :
  localhost:25 cannot be opened
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you have no SMTP server running inside of the container, then you should provide the host etc. of the server you'd like to use with `sendmail`. It can be e.g. gmail or the parent host.

Comment: is installing sendmail in the container a simple alternative? if i go the gmail route how do i set me credentials? Thanks!

Comment: It depends if you are better with sysadmin tasks or reading R docs :)